# algebraic rearrangement, $C=h/[m(t_1-t_2)]$ Solve for $t_1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$ C=\frac{h}{m(t_1-t_2)} $$
>
> Solve for $t_1$.

The correct answer I have been given is, $t_1=t_2-h/(mC)$.  I just need help in the steps taken to reach this.

Comment: If you plan on participating in Math.SE you'll probably want to learn how to post mathematical expressions using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.  I will try and format your expressions for you to give an idea how editing works.  Please check my effort to see I misunderstood something.

Comment: Note that the "correct answer... given" is a solution for $t_1$, not for $t_2$ as you had requested.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the order to do this:

$$C=\frac{h}{m(t_1-t_2)}$$
$$C \,m\,(t_1-t_2)=h$$
$$ t_1-t_2=\frac{h}{C \,m}$$
$$-t_2 = -t_1 + \frac{h}{C\,m}$$ 
$$t_2 = t_1 -\frac{h}{C\,m}$$

Also, I believe you may have copied the answer done incorrectly because in the title you specified solve for $t_2$, but on the question description you posted $t_1 = t_2 -\frac{h}{C\,M}$ which is not true.